# Replace characters in string with a custom alphabet

Tags: java

I have written this code that replaces the characters in a string with a custom supplied alphabet:

```
//Replaces characters in string with custom alphabet.
public static String getStringWithCustomAlphabet(String string, String customAlphabet){
    String shiftedString = "";

    //Loop through every character in @plainText
    for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {

        //Store current character of loop in @charToAdd
        char charToAdd = string.charAt(i);

        int index = getAlphabet().indexOf(charToAdd);

        //If index is valid
        if (index != -1) charToAdd = customAlphabet.charAt(index);

        //Add the character to @cipherText
        shiftedString += charToAdd;
    }

    return shiftedString;
}

public static String getAlphabet() {
    return "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ";
}
```

This code works. However, I want to be able to use not only a String alphabet but an integer alphabet. So, for example:

```
int[] numberArray {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26};
getStringWithCustomAlphabet("abcxyz", numberArray); //Should return 0,1,2,23,24,25
```

Maybe there is some way to simply this code and not use a for loop?

Comment: Make your custom alphabet (regardless if the custom alphabet is letters or numbers) a char array instead of a string and your life will be easier.

Comment: So what is stopping you from creating a overload of the method that takes and returns `int[]` instead of `String`?

Comment: @Andreas Good idea. That would double the amount of code required though. A necessary evil I guess?

Comment: @Provision Since your parameter types are different, it has to be an overload.

Answer (score 0):

For lower case use this :

```
String str = "abcdef";
char[] ch  = str.toCharArray();
for (char c : ch) {
   int temp = (int) c;
   int temp_integer = 96; //for lower case
   if (temp <= 122 & temp >= 97)
      System.out.print(temp-temp_integer);
}
```

> Output will be -:123456

For Upper case :

```
String str = "DEFGHI";
char[] ch  = str.toCharArray();
for (char c : ch) {
   int temp = (int) c;
   int temp_integer = 64; //for upper case
   if (temp <= 90 & temp >= 65)
      System.out.print(temp-temp_integer);
}
```

> Output Will be -:456789

Answer (score 0):

[Strategy](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy) pattern may save you a lot of time and give you maximum flexibility. Suppose that we define an `AlphabetConverter` interface, as:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface AlphabetConverter {
    String convert(char ch);
}
```

Then, define the `convertAlphabet` method accepting an `AlphabetConverter`, as:

```
public String convertAlphabet(String actual, AlphabetConverter converter) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < actual.length(); i++) {
        sb.append(converter.convert(actual.charAt(i)));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Now, you can implement `AlphabetConverter`, one for replacement with `String` alphabet, and one for `int` array, or even use a lambda function.